# problem with starting roscore

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello together,

first at all, im a pretty ros-rookie.

Starting roscore occurs following failures:

> faps@UbuntuBioMech:~$ roscore ...
> logging to
> /home/faps/.ros/log/a1b68836-ea2a-11e1-9b31-000c295e6a98/roslaunch-UbuntuBioMech-9916.log
> Checking log directory for disk usage.
> This may take awhile. Press Ctrl-C to
> interrupt Done checking log file disk
> usage. Usage is <1GB.
>
> started roslaunch server
> http://UbuntuBioMech:45736/ ros_comm
> version 1.8.6
>
> ## SUMMARY
>
> PARAMETERS  * /rosdistro  *
> /rosversion
>
> NODES
>
> auto-starting new master Exception
> AttributeError:
> AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object
> has no attribute '_Thread__block'",)
> in <module 'threading' from
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'>
> ignored process[master]: started with
> pid [9932]
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://UbuntuBioMech:11311/
>
> setting /run_id to
> a1b68836-ea2a-11e1-9b31-000c295e6a98
> Exception AttributeError:
> AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object
> has no attribute '_Thread__block'",)
> in <module 'threading' from
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'>
> ignored process[rosout-1]: started
> with pid [9945] started core service
> [/rosout

]

The [ROS-Workaround](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup#Single_machine_configuration) for this problem didnt work.

Any Sugesstions what is going wrong?
Many thanks ahead,

Dominik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41809/problem-with-starting-roscore/) by [rosrookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3050/rosrookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2012-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a restrictive error. It has to do with Python. For all my purposes, this has not been an issue to the system. Have a look at this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/37087/potential-python-problem-in-ubuntu-1204-lts-64bit-and-fuerte/).

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3